# Detecting network traffic in Firebase with CoffeeScript / Node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, firebase

I'm using a CoffeeScript script to fetch and write product data(base) into Firebase. The script writes a large chunk of product information at once.

Is there a way to detect when Firebase has done writing the data to the backend?

Comment: There sure is. Firebase `set` operations have a completion callback. `ref.set(yourBigObject, function(error) { if (!error) { ... } });` See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html. If you provide the code in question, I can provide a more specific answer if needed.

Comment: Yes, I know about the completion callback, but I was looking to monitor ALL the on-going updates (or network traffic) from a single place. What I could do with the completion callbacks is to have a global "count of on-going operations" increased every time `set` is called and have it decreased on the completion. And monitor the count variable to see if there is on-going activity.

Comment: You can add a listener to all children of the root (but that seems pretty heavy weight).